# JApplicationCli Cronjob

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have the following script:

```
// Initialize Joomla framework
const _JEXEC = 1;

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php'))
{
    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Get the framework.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';

// Bootstrap the CMS libraries.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

/**
 * Cron job to trash expired cache data.
 *
 * @since  2.5
 */
class DoCron extends JApplicationCli
{

    public function doExecute()
    {

        echo 'ok3';
        $this->out('Fetching updates...');

    }

}

JApplicationCli::getInstance('DoCron')->execute();
```

I have added this in CPanel with a Cronjob and get the results of excecution by e-mail.

Now I hoped for an e-mail with 'ok3' or 'Fetching updates...' but none of that all. I do get an e-mail but it is an reference to php excecution.

When I add an 'echo ok' tag right before:

```
JApplicationCli::getInstance('DoCron')->execute();
```

I get that 'ok' as a result in the e-mail.

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here? The script is based on general scripts coming with joomla 3.6.5. Those scripts also give no result.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out that the default php binary for most hosts is the PHP CGI. Running under PHP CGI results in no stdout, stderr and stdin which is why you are not seeing the correct output.

Instead, check your CPanel documentation and look for the CLI version of PHP. It is most likely called php-cli. For example, I had to run a cron job for a Joomla CLI app and found the following to work:

```
/usr/bin/php-cli /path/to/joomla/cli/my-cli -a b -c d --verbose
```